# .htaccess - Different Url Different Request

Tags: .htaccess

I'm try to make one trick for my webpage but I don't have any idea to make it that.

if my url is 
**mydomain.com/eu/en/home/11-item-item.html**.
I want to add this **?SubmitCurrency=anything&id_currency=1** in last of that url.
But just only for one time adding this and not showing users is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(eu/en/home/11-item-item\.html)$ $1?SubmitCurrency=anything&id_currency=1 [L]
```